# Problem with select smaller shapes in database

Tags: mysql, sql, geo, points

Need your help. I have problems with select in ST_Overlaps.

I want to find a shape that doesn't have smaller shapes that fall into this shape.

On picture I want find green blocks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2pXs.png)

I have geometry field in MySQL with coords. And do that:

```
SELECT id 
FROM figureCoords 
HAVING 
  COUNT(
   st_distance(geo_area,(SELECT geo_area FROM figureCoords))=0
  )=0
```

MySQL don't want work with array in the st_distance.

How can I find this fields?

Answer (score 0):

I think you an use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT id 
FROM figureCoords fc
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM figureCoords fc2
                  WHERE st_distance(fc2.geo_area, fc2.geo_area) = 0 AND
                        fc2.id <> fc.id
                 );
```